# SwiftUI: Error while using if #available while trying to build to iOS 13 and iOS 14 in Xcode 12 beta 2

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13

So I'm trying to make it so that my app can deploy on iOS 13 (technically I'm wanting iOS 13.5) as well as iOS 14 so I've written these lines of code to test it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            List {
                Text("Cool!")
                Text("Cool!")
                Text("Cool!")
                Text("Cool!")
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            
        } else {
            List {
                Text("Cool!")
                Text("Cool!")
                Text("Cool!")
                Text("Cool!")
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
        }
    }
}
```

Building to iOS 14 works great, however, whenever I build to iOS 13.5 on a physical phone and the simulator, I get this error in the AppDelegate:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

I've made sure to set my iOS Deployment Target to iOS 13.5 and I'm using Xcode 12 beta 2. I have tried using beta 1 with the same result (though I used the same file, so potentially that's why?). I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong or if this is a bug. When using the code for iOS 13.5 alone (without the if #available) it works as expected, but only when I add that checker is when my problems arise. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yup, I can reproduce. Good instructions!

Comment: I'd file a bug if I were you. A breakpoint shows that we are not entering the first wing of the condition on iOS 13. If you comment out just `.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())` we compile and run fine on iOS 13, proving that this is the source of the issue. But the mere presence of this modifier, not actually encountered in execution, should not crash us. You cannot solve the problem with conditional compilation because you can't test for version.

Comment: When removing the listStyle it fixed it for me too, which is weird! I've filed a bug report, so hopefully it gets fixed soon!

Comment: Maybe the `if` is just not permitted here, but then you'd think the compiler would complain.

Comment: @matt yeah I've tried many things, and I haven't yet found a workaround!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately i can reproduce this bug in Xcode 12 beta 4, so here a workaround. You can wrap iOS 14 code into `AnyView` and all will compile successfully. In this particular case you can use the `ViewModifier` to make code look more swifty.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Cool!")
            Text("Cool!")
        }
        .modifier(GroupedListModifier())
    }
}

struct GroupedListModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                AnyView(
                    content
                        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                )
            } else {
                content
                    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                    .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This bug should be fixed in Xcode 12 beta 5 and later. If it's not, please use Feedback Assistant to report the issue.

For anyone who's curious, the problem was that, even though the iOS 14 branch wasn't taken on iOS 13 devices, the types of the views that *would* have been produced by that branch were still being processed by SwiftUI, and some of those types didn't exist in iOS 13. [The `AnyView` workaround suggested by @pacification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63324384/41222) works because it hides the type information in the iOS 14 branch so that SwiftUI doesn't process it unless that branch is taken. And in fact, Xcode 12 beta 5 basically fixes this bug by automatically wrapping the `if #available` branch in `AnyView`.

Comment: Way cool and thanks for this explanation! Sounds like some kind of eager optimization is tripping us up. Cool bug, eh?